# How can I fork two programs to the background using one line of bash and possibly an ampersand?

Tags: bash, background-process

I have two programs that run indefinitely.  I know I can fork one to the background then run the other by typing this at the command line:

```
> program1 &
> program2 &
```

However, I'm lazy and don't want to hit enter, I just want to run them both immediately.  But bash complains when I do this:

```
> program1 &; program2 &
```

How can I run them both at the same time?

Comment: The following are command separators: `;`, `&`, `&&`, `||` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You leave out the ';' char, i.e.

```
 program1 &  program2 &
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your second example won't work.  If `program1` never exits, `program2` will never run.

Answer (score 7):

try

```
(program1 &) ; (program2 &)
```